# How to use typescript typings without breaking code splitting feature?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, code-splitting

I have a React-App initialized with 'create react-app my-app --template typescript' and i want to use code splitting for a big package. So i am using:

```
import('very-big-package').then(
    coolStuff => {
        ...do some crazy stuff with 'coolStuff'
    }
)
```

Now i want to pass the imported 'coolStuff' to another class constructor:

```
import('very-big-package').then(
    coolStuff => {
        return new OtherClass(coolStuff);
    }
)
```

So how do i define the typings in the 'OtherClass' constructor without using a regular import like:

```
import coolStuff from 'very-big-package'  //which will overrides the dynamic import
class OtherClass{
     constructor(arg:typeof coolStuff){
         ...working with arg
     }
}
```

Comment: i usually use react-loadable for this. Works with typescript https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable

Comment: I'm unsure but you could try this: 1. In `very-big-package`, export a type `type CoolStuff = typeof coolStuff`. 2. Then I think you could try to use `import type CoolStuff from 'very-big-package'` from outside.

Comment: @Paleo 'very-big-package' is a fictional **public** package, so i don't can code anything inside of it

Comment: @Fabian However maybe you should try to use `import type` from [TS 3.8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-8/#type-only-imports-exports).

Comment: @Paleo i have tried:
`import type coolStuff from 'very-big-package';`
VSC says everything is fine but when compiling:
**Line 2:12:  Parsing error: '=' expected**

Comment: Maybe you use an old version of TS?